# How to call custom preference

Tags: java, android, xml

Hi I'm trying to call a custom preference. Why does the application crash?

When I set up the custom preference in preference.xml, the application breaks at "com.appdev.customprefs.SeekBarPreference". I want it to use SeekBarPreference.java and I thought I needed to include the package.SeekBarPreference to get it to work.

xml/preferences.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <com.appdev.customprefs.SeekBarPreference
        android:title="Custom Preference"
        android:key="customPref"
        android:defaultValue="32""/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

stacktrace

> 11-17 20:02:17.920: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:18.100: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:18.100: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:19.080: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:19.080: I/Choreographer(1482): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   11-17 20:02:19.080: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:19.110: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:19.130: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:19.271: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:19.271: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:19.290: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:19.340: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:19.360: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:19.360: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:19.360: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:19.360: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:19.360: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:19.380: D/gralloc_goldfish(1482): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
>   11-17 20:02:19.530: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:19.580: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:21.980: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:21.980: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:22.011: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:22.020: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:22.080: D/dalvikvm(1482): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 115K, 9% free 2602K/2836K, paused 39ms, total 42ms
>   11-17 20:02:22.090: I/dalvikvm-heap(1482): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.259MB for 635812-byte allocation
>   11-17 20:02:22.200: D/dalvikvm(1482): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 7% free 3220K/3460K, paused 120ms, total 120ms
>   11-17 20:02:22.470: D/dalvikvm(1482): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 7% free 3239K/3460K, paused 81ms+130ms, total 266ms
>   11-17 20:02:22.521: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:22.530: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:22.580: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:22.710: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:22.760: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:22.760: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:22.790: I/Choreographer(1482): Skipped 67 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   11-17 20:02:22.790: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:22.790: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:22.810: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:22.860: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:22.870: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:22.910: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:22.960: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:22.960: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:23.010: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:23.020: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:23.080: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:23.160: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:23.852: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:23.852: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:23.890: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:23.890: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:23.920: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:23.920: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:23.970: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:23.970: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:23.970: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:23.970: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:24.010: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:24.010: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:24.030: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:24.030: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:24.050: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:24.050: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:24.142: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:24.142: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:24.180: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:24.180: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:24.554: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:24.572: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:24.650: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:24.650: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:24.650: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:24.650: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:24.670: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:24.670: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:24.810: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:24.810: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:24.820: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:24.820: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:24.820: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:24.880: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:24.940: W/Trace(1482): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
>   11-17 20:02:25.410: D/AndroidRuntime(1482): Shutting down VM
>   11-17 20:02:25.410: W/dalvikvm(1482): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
>   11-17 20:02:25.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1482): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   11-17 20:02:25.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1482): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.appdev.customprefs/com.appdev.customprefs.preferences}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #4: Error inflating class com.appdev.customprefs.SeekBarPreference
>   11-17 20:02:25.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
>   11-17 20:02:25.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
>   11-17 20:02:25.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>   11-17 20:02:25.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
>   11-17 20:02:25.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   11-17 20:02:25.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   11-17 20:02:25.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
>   11-17 20:02:25.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   11-17 20:02:25.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   11-17 20:02:25.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   11-17 20:02:25.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>   11-17 20:02:25.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   11-17 20:02:25.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1482): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #4: Error inflating class com.appdev.customprefs.SeekBarPreference
>   11-17 20:02:25.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:386)
>   11-17 20:02:25.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItemFromTag(GenericInflater.java:430)
>   11-17 20:02:25.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:481)
>   11-17 20:02:25.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:493)
>   11-17 20:02:25.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:326)
>   11-17 20:02:25.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:263)
>   11-17 20:02:25.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:269)
>   11-17 20:02:25.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at android.preference.PreferenceActivity.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceActivity.java:1424)
>   11-17 20:02:25.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at com.appdev.customprefs.preferences.onCreate(preferences.java:12)
>   11-17 20:02:25.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
>   11-17 20:02:25.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
>   11-17 20:02:25.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
>   11-17 20:02:25.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     ... 11 more
>   11-17 20:02:25.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1482): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:  [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
>   11-17 20:02:25.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
>   11-17 20:02:25.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:431)
>   11-17 20:02:25.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:377)
>   11-17 20:02:25.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1482):     ... 22 more
>   11-17 20:02:28.760: I/Process(1482): Sending signal. PID: 1482 SIG: 9

SeekBarPreference.java

```
public class SeekBarPreference extends Preference implements OnSeekBarChangeListener
{

public SeekBarPreference(Context context)
{   
    super(context);
    Log.i("SBP", "In SBP!");
}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.i("SBP", "In SBP2!");
    return super.onCreateView(parent);
}

}
```

Comment: can you please post your stacktrace?

Comment: I added a stacktrace to the original post since it was too long to add here.

Comment: Is SeekBarPreference Inner Class?

Comment: No. It is in it's own file SeekBarPreference.java

Comment: Do you have a Constructor for SeekBarPreference Class?

Comment: Yes, I had methods all fleshed out. I stubbed them to try to track down the source of the error. I've added SeekBarPreference.java to the main post. At this point I'm just trying to get the Log "In SBP!".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You implemented only one constructor. To be able use Preference , you should implement 2 other constructors from Preference :

Just Implement These Two Constructor also:

```
Preference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)

Preference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
```

Here your log:
**Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]**